# unresolved dependency for rxjava cannot download rxjava.jar

Tags: java, android, android-studio, rx-java, rx-java2

I never used this library. It cannot sync properly but  my internet is working good enough to download that .jar file

Here is my error:

> Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not  download rxjava.jar (io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.0)
>   Open File
>   Show Details
>
> Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not download rxjava.jar (io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.0)
>   Open File
>   Show Details
>
> Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not download rxjava.jar (io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.0)
>   Open File
>   Show Details
>
> Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not download rxjava.jar (io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.0)
>   Open File
>   Show Details
>
> Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not download rxjava.jar (io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.0)
>   Open File
>   Show Details

Here is my build.app gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tekemuradov.aman.ulgmada"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    // implement support libraries
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'

    // implement firebase libraries
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'

    // implement firebase-ui
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:2.3.0'

    // implement lifecycle
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.0'

    // implement circle image view
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'

    // implement image cropper
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.+'

    // implement image compressor
    implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'

    // implement test
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'


}



apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

configurations.all{
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency{DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if(requested.group == 'com.android.support'){
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")){
                details.useVersion('27.0.2')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

here is my build.project gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'




        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.3'
```

from https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/5794